# How to check if Scanln throws an error in Golang

Tags: go, panic

I am new to Go. I've been searching for answers and I know there really is one I just haven't found it.

To better explain my question, here is my code:

```
func main() {

    ...

    inputs := new(Inputs)

    fmt.Println("Input two numbers: ")

    fmt.Scanln(&inputs.A)
    fmt.Scanln(&inputs.B)

    fmt.Println("Sum is:", inputs.A + inputs.B)
}
```

And here is my struct:

```
type Inputs struct {
    A, B int
}
```

If I will input '123' for Input A and another '123' for Input B, I will have an output of "***Sum is: 246***". But if I will mistakenly input *'123j'* , it will no longer work since A and B accept int(s) only.

Now, how to catch the panic from *fmt.Scanln* or is there a way? Thanks in advance.

Comment: [RTFM](https://golang.org/pkg/fmt/#Scanln) *before* asking basic questions.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[Scanln returns values](https://golang.org/pkg/fmt/#Scanln) ... *don't ignore them*.

You're ignoring two important return values. The count of the scan and an error .. if there was one.

```
n, err := fmt.Scanln(&inputs.A)
```

...will give you what you need to check. `err` will tell you that a newline was expected and wasn't found .. because you've tried to store the value in an `int` .. and it [errors when the last character in the available value isn't a newline](https://golang.org/src/fmt/scan.go#L1061).